# CrudRepository Spring Data @Query syntax

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The @Query annotation supports only JPA query syntax or Hibernate (HQL)? or both of them i am kinda confused

```
interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> { 

@Async
@Query("SELECT t.title FROM Todo t where t.id = :id") 
Book<String> findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: you can even try native queries using nativeQuery = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringData repositories support JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language).

Though JPQL is a subset of HQL so any JPQL query is a valid HQL query.
The inverse is obviously not true.